# I want to have my form show an error and not be able to pass when someone doesnt enter a field correctly, but how?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Here's the form, found on a webpage named genericwebpage.html

```
<form name = "quoted" form action = "genericwebpage.php" method="get">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">        <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
<input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```

and heres the php, found on genericwebpage.php

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
<div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_GET['actual-quote']?></div>
<div class="poster"><?php echo $_GET['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

Can someone guide me to a point where an error box will show up when entered not fully and so it will not be submitted? I've looked at tutorials but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: JavaScript, Ajax if you want to go down the non submit route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the inputs you want to be required

```
required="required"
```

will stop the submission and point out the required field in most modern browsers.  For a more in - depth response you will need JavaScript.